# The type of expression must be an array type but it resolved to string

Tags: android

am developing a application which fetches some data from Database..but it shows this error

```
private void add() {


    db = (new DbHelper(this)).getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "select * from stock where product = ?";
    String list_data;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] { list_data });
    c.moveToFirst();

    final CharSequence[] items = new CharSequence[list_data.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < list_data.length(); i++) {


        items[i] = list_data[i];//here is the error
    }
```

Comment: This is a string: `String list_data;` it can't be used as an array.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve but the error is pretty much self-explanatory, list_data[i] is not going to work because list_data is a String and you're trying to use it like an array...

Comment: Here you are making a loop on the number of characters in the string`for (int i = 0; i < list_data.length(); i++) {`. But this number is 0, since the string hasn't been assigned any value.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks any understanding of what he is doing

Comment: why are you not use toCharArray() to String class ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
db = (new DbHelper(this)).getReadableDatabase();
String query = "select * from stock where product = ?";
String list_data;
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] { list_data });
c.moveToFirst();

final CharSequence[] items = new CharSequence[list_data.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < list_data.length(); i++) {


       items[i] = list_data.charAt(i);
}
```

You can get char from String using charAt(int index) method

Comment: But list_data is **empty**, since it was never assigned any value.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable, **list_data** by virtue of being a String variable cannot be used like an array. When I say it cannot be used as an array, I'm specifically talking about the square brackets you used for referencing individual characters within the string.

> `items[i] = list_data[i];`

As Aniruddh correctly pointed out, you must use the built in charAt() method which is defined under the String class.

> `items[i] = list_data.charAt(i);`

Refer the definition for details-
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29

Cheers.